# Kummer's Theorem for cyclotomic units

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $A=\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ be the ring of integers of the $n$ - th cyclotomic cyclotomic field for $n=32$. It is true that the unit group of A is generated by $\zeta$ and the real units?

I mean... is Kummer's Theorem valid in the general case?

Comment: Dear Jose, I am not familiar with a <<Kummer's Theorem>> in algebraic number theory, what is its statement exactly? Thanks.

Comment: BenjaLim you must to read the answer of Alvaro to my question. The statement is $U(A)=W_{p}(L)\cdot U^{+}$

Comment: "te unit group of A is generated by z and the real units"

Comment: Dear Jose, this theorem is more commonly refered to as Dirichlet's Unit Theorem. Regards,

Comment: thanks Benjali....by the way...did you read my question about a cyclotomic integer ring which is  not norm-euclidean rings?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, let $E$ be the group of units in $\mathcal{O}_K$, let $K^+$ be the maximal real subfield of $K$, and let $E^+$ be the unit group in $\mathcal{O}_{K^+}$. Let $W$ be the group of roots of unity in $K$. Then, $[E:WE^+]=1$ if $n$ is a prime power and $[E:WE^+]=2$ if $n$ is not a prime power.

You can find a proof in Washington's "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields", Corollary 4.13.